# Conflict between webpack-dev-server package and http-proxy-middleware, which is also it's subdependency

Tags: typescript, npm, dependencies, webpack-dev-server

Some time ago i installed `webpack-dev-server` v3.11.0 in my project, which - as i recently checked - has `http-proxy-middleware` v0.19.1 as dependency. It has worked ok until i separately installed `http-proxy-middleware` package, but in v1.1.1. Now, when i build the TS project, it throws the following errors:

```
node_modules/@types/webpack-dev-server/index.d.ts:30:53 - error TS2694: Namespace '"E:/Pro
jects/shop/node_modules/http-proxy-middleware/dist/index"' has no exported me
mber 'Config'.

30         [url: string]: string | httpProxyMiddleware.Config;
                                                       ~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/webpack-dev-server/index.d.ts:36:29 - error TS2694: Namespace '"E:/Pro
jects/shop/node_modules/http-proxy-middleware/dist/index"' has no exported me
mber 'Config'.

36     } & httpProxyMiddleware.Config;
                               ~~~~~~
```

Apparently, `webpack-dev-server` now uses the standalone `http-proxy-middleware` v1.1.1, which i installed, instead of it's *default* subdependent v0.19.1, which differs (at least) in exported *things*.

```
$ npm ls http-proxy-middleware
shop@1.0.0 E:\Projects\shop
+-- http-proxy-middleware@1.1.2
`-- webpack-dev-server@3.11.0
  `-- http-proxy-middleware@0.19.1
```

Is there a way, to force `webpack-dev-server` to still use it's subdependency v0.19.1 while i will be able to use v1.1.1? Or is there a better way that i could use the newer version without such issues?

I read about shrinkwrap, but it seems to be an overkill for that case with just one conflicting package - but maybe i am wrong.

**[update]**

As a workaround i removed standalone `http-proxy-middleware` v1.1.1 package and used `webpack-dev-server` dependency package in my module. However i don't think this is the solution for problem, so i'd like to know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1):

When you do npm audit it notifies you of dependencies.
You can do npm audit fix and it will temporarily fix them but as soon as you install another dependency or do npm install those fixes can get lost.

To ensure usage of a specific dependency for all npm packages you can use an npm package called - npm-force-resolutions

1. install npm-force-resolutions

```
npm i npm-force-resolutions
```

2. Add to package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "node ./node_modules/npm-force-resolutions/index.js"
  }
```

3. declare which version of the dependencies will be used in your other npm packages:
   example
   add to package.json

```
  "resolutions": {
    "minimist": "1.2.5"
  },
```

4. npm install

```
npm i
```

done!

Answer (score 0):

`webpack-dev-server@4.0.0-beta.2` uses `http-proxy-middleware@1.3.0`, maybe upgrade to it already?

Comment: Updating `webpack-dev-server` for me is rather workaround than a proper solution - similarly as using webpack's dependency `http-proxy-middleware` in my module instead of a standalone version. I know it's often better to update packages, but i just would like to be able to use separate version of package as the standalone without having it conflicting with it's dependent package.